# Tengo un array guardado en localstorage, pero cuando accedo, este retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

Tengo este código:

```
let carritos = [];
let productId = 75;
let descrip = "Lorem";

carritos.push({productId, descrip});
let carritoEnJson = JSON.stringify(carritos);
localStorage.setItem('CarritoProductos', carritoEnJson);

let arrayLocal = localStorage.getItem('CarritoProductos');
if (arrayLocal !== "") {
    document.write(arrayLocal[0].productId);
}
```

Y quisiera saber porqué retorna undefined cuando se ejecuta el código...

Comment: El valor almacenado en `localStorage` es una cadena en formato `JSON`. Cuando lo obtienes, debes primero volver a convertirlo en un objeto antes de intentar acceder a las propiedades o valores del mismo. Algo como: `let arrayLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CarritoProductos'));`

Comment: Perfecto!! Funcionó! Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: Te recomiendo postear una respuesta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que lo que se almacena en el [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage) del navegador es en realidad un [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DOMString), que traducido a Javascript es simplemente un objeto de tipo String o lo que conocemos como "cadena".

La solución es analizar (Parse) la cadena que obtienes para convertirla en un objeto de Javascript.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const arrayLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CarritoProductos'));
```

El método [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) analiza una cadena con formato JSON y la transforma en un Objeto de Javascript.

Dado que primero has convertido el ítem "carritos" en una cadena en formato JSON con:

```js
const carritoEnJson = JSON.stringify(carritos);
```

Lo lógico es volver a convertirla en Objeto cuando la obtengas del Storage.

Si no lo haces, al intentar acceder a la propiedad `productId` de `arrayLocal[0]`, te devolverá siempre `undefined`, ya que `arrayLocal` es una cadena y el valor de la posición 0 de dicha cadena es a su vez una cadena, y las cadenas no tienen una propiedad llamada `productId`. Esa es la razón por la que te devuelve `undefined`.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.